# New dataframe based on column headers

Tags: python, pandas, filter, header, columnsorting

I have a large dataframe with 600+ columns

Approx 40 of these will have the word 'austria' in them. If I'm making a new dataframe just for austrian data is there an easy way to create a new data frame based on the column header?

Any help much appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
df2 = df.filter(regex='(?i)austria')  # (?i) makes the search case insensitive
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['austria something', 'something austria',
                           'another austria', 'unrelated', 'Austria again'],
                  index=[0])

df.filter(regex='(?i)austria')
```

output:

```
  austria something something austria another austria Austria again
0               NaN               NaN             NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much! That was perfect. Will accept shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `.loc` which allows you to filter with booleans across a certain index and `.str.contains`

```
df2 = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('austria',case=False)]

  austria something something austria another austria Austria again
0               NaN               NaN             NaN           NaN
```